# Implement SSO react native with Microsoft Azure

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, character-encoding, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on

How do I implement SSO react native with Microsoft Azure? Please explain it in detail. I want a document or a blog that shows steps on implementing single sign on react native with Microsoft Azure. I would like to have the coding part as well.

Comment: Kindly acknowledge my question and help me out

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  This is not your personal recommendation site

Comment: **Azure** has just one "z" - it's not "azzure" ....